# Process.Start does not open applications

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

how can I start 2 processes with the following code:

```
Process.Start(@"D:\Clients\Client1\program.exe");
Process.Start(@"D:\Clients\Client2\program.exe");
```

The routes are functional, the first process always opens

Both applications are the same, and the first application opens successfully for me, but the second application does not open.
For the second application I noticed in the task manager in the details page that the application appears for a few seconds and disappears and does not open
If I open the applications manually it works.

I'm interested in how I could do it to start applications using Process.Start () ?

Comment: Did you know if that application allows only one instance of itself to be running at any time

Comment: @Steve, I don't know, I only know if I run manually it works for me

Comment: If you create a BAT file (or CMD file) that starts those two programs, one right after the other (like you do above), do you see the same behavior?  Something like `@echo off`, `D:\Clients\Client1\program.exe` and `D:\Clients\Client2\program.exe` on separate lines.

Comment: BTW, if my BAT file test shows that the same behavior happens from a batch file, then the problem is with `program.exe`.  It could be (as @Steve) points out that the program only allows a single instance to run.  It could also be that the program attempts to get an exclusive lock on some resource.  It succeeds the first time, but fails with an uncaught exception the second time.  If that's the case, you _may_ see some hint of that in the Event Log (the Windows Event Log)

Comment: @Flydog57 I tried to run them with a .bat file and also only one instance of the application opened. Thanks

Comment: Then the problem is in program.exe, not in your Process.Start code.  Time to shift gears

Comment: Can you give us more information on what is program.exe? Are you on a virtual machine? If you replace program.exe with notepad.exe, do you have two notepad applications launched?

Comment: @FredSmith If I change with notepad.exe, only one application opens, and when I close it, the other one appears, in the process manager I see only one notepad.exe application, and when I close it, a second one appears. I want to mention that I put 2 instances to open from the .bat file. I am on a virtual machine with the Windows 10 operating system

Comment: Notepad.exe doesn't disable several instances of itself so the problem looks like it is coming from your virtual machine setup. Do you have VMware, Citrix, VirtualBox? Are you on a batch file or a Visual Studio code file?

Comment: @FredSmith I tried Visual Studio Code and Batch files. I'm on a remote desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to use this method to see if it solves your problem:

```
public static void StartApplication(string applicationName, string argument = "", bool useShellExecute = true, bool createNoWindow = false)
{
  Process task = new Process
  {
    StartInfo =
    {
      UseShellExecute = useShellExecute,
      FileName = applicationName,
      Arguments = argument,
      CreateNoWindow = createNoWindow
    }
  };

  task.Start();
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
StartApplication(@"D:\Clients\Client1\program.exe");
StartApplication(@"D:\Clients\Client2\program.exe");
```

Comment: Only the first instance opens. The second application is seen in the task manager in the details page that it opens and closes quickly, when the second instance should start, the focus is on the first instance. If I open them manually it works for me

Comment: Is the program.exe version different or similar from client1 and client2?

Comment: Both have the same version

Comment: If you have two batch files and you start one batch file after another, do you have two applications?

Comment: Only one application opens

Comment: Run MSTSC.EXE and go to Experience tab and disable Caching bitmaps and try again, do you have two applications?

Comment: In the same way, only one application opens

Comment: Can we download this program.exe somewhere?